# Vim syntax file for TYPO3 Fluid templates

Tags: vim, typo3, fluid

Where can I find a Vim syntax file for TYPO3 Fluid Templates? If it doesn't exist what syntax file could be used as example to create one?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I created [vim-fluid](https://github.com/mipmip/vim-fluid), a Vim plugin for the Fluid Template Engine offering indention and syntax highlighting for fluid code together with plain HTML and JavaScript and CSS code. It's working for me.

[image]

Comment: That is awesome. will give it a try immediately!

Answer (score 1):

I have not found one for Fluid templates. However, as the file extension is html, I think the easiest way to include Fluid Regions would be to use the html syntax file. If I find the time, I'll give it a shot.

Even though you did not ask, this is what I use for typoscript:

https://github.com/elmar-hinz/vim.typoscript

The syntax highlighting for fluid looks like this for me:

[image: Short fluid template]

So the only two things I really miss are an autoformatter that respects fluid tags as well as a fluid inline syntax highlighter. Otherwise it's quite neat already. Looking forward to other answers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm a happy user of typoscript.vim from elmar-hinz